# Make histogram of pixel intensities without imhist

Tags: matlab, histogram

I have used the `unique` command to get the unique pixel intensities from my image. Then I tried to make a histogram using them, but it doesn't use all of the intensity values

```
I = imread('pout.tif');
[rows, columns] = size(I);
UniquePixels=unique(I);
hist=histogram(UniquePixels)
```

[image]

Comment: do `hist=histogram(I(:),UniquePixels)`. `UniquePixels` are just the unique pixel **values**.

Comment: what's the purpose of the 2nd argument?

Comment: its the histogram bin edges. alternatively you can do `hist=histogram(I(:),0:255)` which will give you 0's for each value which is not exist in the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative approach would be to use [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) combined with [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html).  I would specifically use the third output of `unique` to transform your data into a consecutive sequence of 1 up to `N` where `N` is the total number of unique intensities, then leverage the first output of `unique` that will give you the list of unique intensities.  Therefore, if the first output of `unique` is `A` and the output of `accumarray` is `B`, the effect is that at location `B(i)`, this gives the total number of intensities of `A(i)`.

Therefore:

```
[UniquePixels, ~, id] = unique(I);
histo = accumarray(id, 1);
```

`UniquePixels` gives you all unique pixels while `histo` gives you the counts of each unique pixel corresponding to each element in `UniquePixels`.

Here's a quick example:

```
>> I = randi(255, 10, 10)

I =

    42   115    28   111   218   107   199    60   140   237
   203    22   246   233   159    13   100    91    76   198
    80    59     2    47    90   231    62   210   190   125
   135   233   198    68   131   241   103     4    49   112
    43    39   209    38   103   126    25    11   176   114
   154   211   222    35    20   125    34    44    47    79
    68   138    22   222    62    87   241   166    94   130
   167   255   102   148    32   230   244   187   160   131
   176    20    67   141    47    95   147   166   199   209
   191   113   205    37    62    29    16   115    21   203

>> [UniquePixels, ~, id] = unique(I);
>> histo = accumarray(id, 1);
>> [UniquePixels histo]

ans =

     2     1
     4     1
    11     1
    13     1
    16     1
    20     2
    21     1
    22     2
    25     1
    28     1
    29     1
    32     1
    34     1
    35     1
    37     1
    38     1
    39     1
    42     1
    43     1
    44     1
    47     3
    49     1
    59     1
    60     1
    62     3
    67     1
    68     2
    76     1
    79     1
    80     1
    87     1
    90     1
    91     1
    94     1
    95     1
   100     1
   102     1
   103     2
   107     1
   111     1
   112     1
   113     1
   114     1
   115     2
   125     2
   126     1
   130     1
   131     2
   135     1
   138     1
   140     1
   141     1
   147     1
   148     1
   154     1
   159     1
   160     1
   166     2
   167     1
   176     2
   187     1
   190     1
   191     1
   198     2
   199     2
   203     2
   205     1
   209     2
   210     1
   211     1
   218     1
   222     2
   230     1
   231     1
   233     2
   237     1
   241     2
   244     1
   246     1
   255     1
```

If you double check the input example and the final output, you will see that only the unique pixels are shown combined with their counts.  Any bins that were zero in count are not shown.